# Parse.com counting elements on Installations returns two numbers

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, parse-platform, request

Thanks in advance.

I have a custom field in my installation table in PARSE.COM, on it I have the users (the systems it´s multiuser) in an array like this:

```
["user1","user2",...]
```

In certain cases this field it´s like this:

```
[""]
```

Right.

When I query finding "user1" I recibe 2 results, first one witch I expected (number of installations using the user "user1"), and the second one I think it´s the installations without values, but an empty array.

I receive this:

```
Array
(
[results] => Array()
[count] => 2
)
Array
(
[results] => Array()
[count] => 0
)
```

Here sending query:

```
$queryString = http_build_query( array('limit'=>0, 'count'=>1, 'where'=>'{"usuarioslist":{ "$in": [ "user1" ]}}') );
    $result = ParseClient::_request('GET',
        '/1/installations'.
        '?' . $queryString, null, null, true);
```

The problem comes when I send a push message with same query... it goes to the users "user1" and the empty ones... it´s very frustrating.

Please help.

Comment: it's an array of objects, not a relationship

Comment: (that was a question) - a relationship would be much better, also, why do you have an array with an empty string?

Comment: Thanks guys but this is not the question. The question is when I call the api allways get twice, although I query channels field in installations, for example.

Comment: I'm just 1 person :) and I ask about the relationship because it should be more reliable than the array query (where I guess you're running into an implementation detail to get a false positive though I'm not sure)